# Excess height on the text of button

Tags: css

I've a small problem with text-align of my button.

Here's the button itself:

[image]

It has same padding:

[image]

But, the link itself gives extra height, not 2.3rem how I ask it to.

[image]

You can see that highlighted link gives extra space at the bottom, it's not centrelized.

Maybe someone know how to fix it?

Html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn get-started__btn">Proceed to the Brief</a>
```

SCSS:

```
.btn{
    &,
    &:link,
    &:visited{
        color: $color-white;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: none;
        border-radius: $border-radius-medium;
        background-color: $color-candy;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 1.5rem 5rem;
        font-size: 2.3rem;
        @include FilsonProRegular;
        text-align: center;

        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: all .2s;
        white-space: nowrap;

        @include respond(tab-port){
            padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
        }

        @include respond(phone){
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PS: Line-height not help

Comment: can you share what styles you applied to the button.

Comment: use letter like `jpq` and see the result

Comment: You should post CSS code only if you want people to look at your styles, its easier for people to have the css code to go ahead and test your code right away

Comment: Please add the CSS for class `get-started__btn`, thanks.

Comment: I added CSS for .btn , 
I don't have any styles for '.get-started__btn', added class in case if client wants to add some margins etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TemaniAfif said, that space is for the *descender* that certain characters like <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>ç</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> etc have. And you seem to be using a custom font with rather large descenders.

[image]

See [explanation on fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-1/type-anatomy/anatomy).

Comment: Thank you, mate. Nice info!